# Codename One App Crashes if Minimised while Virtual Keyboard is Showing

Tags: codenameone

I create a form then add a text field and I run this on an Android device (have not tried on anything else). If I click into the text field to bring up the virtual keyboard, minimise the app then resume it again, it causes the app to stop responding. I have tried calling .stopEditing() from the stop() method but there is no change.

How do I stop the app from crashing?

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    tf = new TextField();
    hi.add(tf);
    hi.show();
}
```

Please ignore the above code, the code that causes the issue is below:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
    dlg.add(new TextField());
    hi.show();
    dlg.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    if(current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog)current).dispose();
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }
}


01-10 06:35:09.516: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.516: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.526: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.536: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.536: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.536: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.746: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.746: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:09.756: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:11.406: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:11.406: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:11.406: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{28390f44 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=201 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:18.346: E/Watchdog(1000): !@Sync 403 [01-10 06:35:18.349]
01-10 06:35:42.116: E/AutomaticBrightnessController(1000): [DAB] printLastLightSensorEvent : lastLightSensorEventTime = 12151387 lastLightSensorValue = 36.0
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): ANR in com.mycompany.myapp (com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub)
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): PID: 11174
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 21.  Wait queue head age: 20538.4ms.)
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): Load: 12.27 / 89.36 / 137.01
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): CPU usage from 0ms to 7676ms later:
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   75% 1000/system_server: 26% user + 48% kernel / faults: 10929 minor 338 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   10% 1247/com.android.systemui: 3.5% user + 6.7% kernel / faults: 3308 minor 81 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   5.1% 1471/com.android.phone: 2.3% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 3809 minor 94 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 343/debuggerd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3623 minor 103 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   1.3% 1449/com.android.nfc: 0.6% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 2691 minor 749 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   4.5% 11174/com.mycompany.myapp: 3.5% user + 1% kernel / faults: 2508 minor 79 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0% 1972/com.android.incallui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1255 minor 281 major
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.9% 253/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.4% 10246/kworker/u:9: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.5% 2033/mpdecision: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.3% 443/adbd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 137 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0% 92/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 6/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0% 438/qmuxd: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 1782/MC_Thread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 1825/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 9866/logcat: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 10256/kworker/u:19: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 14924/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0% 15446/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   0.1% 16499/kworker/0:0H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): 57% TOTAL: 20% user + 35% kernel + 1.3% iowait + 0.1% softirq
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): CPU usage from 7081ms to 7619ms later:
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   12% 1000/system_server: 5.4% user + 7.2% kernel / faults: 10 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):     9% 1103/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 7.2% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):     1.8% 1102/SensorService: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):     1.8% 1227/RegisterInSeper: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   1% 443/adbd: 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 52 minor
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):     1% 443/adbd: 0% user + 1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   1% 2033/mpdecision: 0% user + 1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   1.1% 10256/kworker/u:19: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000):   1.2% 14924/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.656: E/ActivityManager(1000): 20% TOTAL: 4% user + 16% kernel
01-10 06:35:44.736: E/android.os.Debug(1000): ro.product_ship = true
01-10 06:35:44.736: E/android.os.Debug(1000): ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
01-10 06:35:47.756: E/InputDispatcher(1000): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-10 06:35:47.766: E/OpenGLRenderer(1000): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
01-10 06:35:47.776: E/ViewRootImpl(1000): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-10 06:35:47.936: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.936: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.936: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.936: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.946: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.946: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.946: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:47.946: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.336: E/Watchdog(1000): !@Sync 404 [01-10 06:35:48.350]
01-10 06:35:48.346: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.346: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.346: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.346: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.356: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.356: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.356: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.356: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.366: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.366: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.366: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499 
01-10 06:35:48.366: E/WindowState(1000): getStack: Window{2317c356 u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub} couldn't find taskId=202 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499
```

Comment: Which OS version/model? Can you try this with a cable connected and see if you can see a stack trace in DDMS?

Comment: I only have two Android devices and it happens on both. One is a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active SM-T365 running Android version 5.1.1 and the other is a Motorola Nexus 6 running Android version 7.0. I have not used DDMS but will give it a go later when I get time.

Comment: DDMS shows this a number of times: 12-31 05:35:58.562: E/WindowState(982): getStack: Window{1396b53a u0 d0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.KeyboardTestStub} couldn't find taskId=3 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1066 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1791 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2385 com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:1499

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this and that stack doesn't seem related. Are you building using versioned build to an older Codename One version? Are you seeing this in current builds from our servers? I've tested mostly on Android 6 but if it happens both in 5.x and 7.x it should probably happen in 6.x too...

Comment: My original issue was with a textfield in a Dialog. I tried to simplify the issue in a test app but didn’t realise that I still had ‘.stopEditing()’ in the stop() method which was causing a new ‘not responding issue’. Please see the relevant code from my new test case with a Dialog where the ‘not responding issue’ is still happening.

Comment: Do you have a stack on this new issue? Notice that this is more likely an issue with the dialog than with the text field.

Comment: I have a stack but it is too long to include all here. I did find: 01-09 08:04:06.785: E/ActivityManager(1000): ANR in com.mycompany.myapp (com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub)
01-09 08:04:06.785: E/ActivityManager(1000): PID: 29486
01-09 08:04:06.785: E/ActivityManager(1000): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 14.  Wait queue head age: 20523.6ms.)
Are you not able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I haven't tried the new issue but the original issue you submitted doesn't happen. Since we are in code freeze right now and pretty busy due to the release we don't have available resources. You can edit the question and add the stack trace information there. Then add a comment here so I get notified of the change.

Comment: I have added the stack trace (it was still too long so I removed a load of duplicated lines from the top). This issue is a major one for any apps that use a login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably an issue with the text field during one of our weekly updates. Adding/remove the plugin doesn't change anything since native device build occurs only on the servers, as long as you don't use [versioned builds](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---get-repeatable-builds-build-against-a-consistent-version-of-codename-one-use-the-versioning-feature.html) this should update every Friday.

Comment: I have just tried again (Saturday morning) and this is still an issue. (I am not using versioned builds).

Comment: Do you have any specific build hints in place? Try showing the dialog using the modless mode and see if it works around the issue

Comment: I do not have any build hints in place. It is the same with showModeless. I just created a new project and tested it on yet another Tablet - Lenovo TAB2 A10-30 Android version 5.51. From my testing so far, it looks like this affects all Android devices.

Comment: Odd, we'll try to look into it.

Comment: Should I raise it as a issue on Github?

Comment: No need. We fixed it already but since it didn't make 3.6 and we are skipping this Friday release (due to the release) this will only be available next Friday (24th of January 2017)